# MySQL InnoDB Create FK error

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to create a self-referential FK:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Company`;
CREATE TABLE `Company` (
  `company_id`        INTEGER(32) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_company_id` INTEGER(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `Company` 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY `parent_company_id` REFERENCES `Company`(`company_id`);
```

I am getting the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES `Company`(`company_id`)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

You gotta change the definition of

`parent_company_id` INTEGER(32)

To match company_id except for the autoincrement and then use this statement

```
ALTER TABLE `Company` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_parent_company_id FOREIGN KEY (`parent_company_id`) REFERENCES `Company`(`company_id`)
```

So basically remember to put unsigned on the column you are using as FK so it matches the definition of the referenced key